# Create a TDataModule only once

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to build a `procedure` that creates a `TDataModule` in `Application` as its parent.

The problem is, the second time I call the `procedure`, the `dm` parameter still `nil`. I expect something diferent of `nil` considering that it was created before.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
procedure UseDataModule(dm : TDataModule; cClass:TcomponentClass);
begin
    if dm = nil then
        cClass.Create(Application);
end;
```

There are some requirements I want for this `procedure`:

1. The given `TDataModule` should be created once
2. It must to be created by `procedure` because I want to use It sometimes, that's why I don't put it in auto-create forms
3. Its parent will be always `Application`

Comment: You are omitting to assign the result of `cClass.Create(Application)` to anything.  If you want the result to be assigned to `dm` then as well as your code making the actuall assignment, `dm` needs to be a `var` parameter otherwise the result will be discarded after UseDataModule exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
procedure UseDataModule(var dm : TDataModule; cClass:TcomponentClass);
//  the `var` qualifier is to allow the value of `dm` to be retained 
//  after `UseDataModule` exits, otherwise the Created instance will be discarded
//  and you will have a memory leak
begin
  if dm = nil then
    dm := cClass.Create(Application);
end;
```

Imo, it would be better to code `UseDataModule` as a function, but that is largely a matter of taste.  Note also that you could write `if notAssigned(dm)` instead of `if dm = Nil`.

I gather from your comment that you have decided to use the following code instead of my initial suggestion:

```
  procedure UseDataModule(var dm : TDataModule; cClass:TcomponentClass);   
  begin 
    if dm = nil then begin 
      dm := cClass.Create(Application) as TDataModule; 
    end; 
  end;
```

which seems fine to me.

Comment: `dm = nil` should be replaced with `not assigned()` which is more verbose

Comment: With respect I disagree, it should be a matter of personal preference, imo.  `= Nil` is transparent and self-documenting, `unassigned` is opaque and, as you say, verbose..

Comment: Purpose of `Assigned`: to verify that method/function is assigned. Read more at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Assigned

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for your response. I did a little change in your code casting the created object as TDataModule. It is what I need.

`procedure UseDataModule(var dm : TDataModule; cClass:TcomponentClass);
begin
    if dm = nil then begin
        dm := cClass.Create(Application) as TDataModule;
    end;
end;`

Please, change yor code so I can accept it as the correct solution

Comment: Updated as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the same code used to autocreate forms with a check to see if it is already created.

```
  // Create data module if it doesn't already exist
  if DM = nil then Application.CreateForm(TDM, DM);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your solution before, and it gave me the same result. The DM parameter continues nil, no matter how many times I call the procedure.